# How to connect Cassandra with Spark using Java.

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and need help with implementing a simple program with Spark and connecting to cassandra.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

If any one can come up with a working solution and build the above as a JAR file it will be a good kickstart for me.

I have successfully installed Spark as well as Cassandra and both are running on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Spark Cassandra connector [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).

It has some example programs for Java.  It takes some effort to set it up, so you'll need to read the documentation in the github project.

Comment: Ok thank u so much for helpful post, I will go through this article.